# Inheritance security rules violated by type: 'System.Net.Http.WebRequestHandler'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config

I have the following assembly reference in the web.config of an MVC application...

```
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.1.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Every time I install or update any nuget package, the version number is automatically updated to 4.1.1.0. However this then completely breaks my application. It displays the error...

> Inheritance security rules violated by type:
>   'System.Net.Http.WebRequestHandler'. Derived types must either match
>   the security accessibility of the base type or be less accessible.

I've found other questions, where the proposed solution is to change the version number back again. This however doesn't seem particularly satisfactory. There must be some underlying problem that's causing me to have to always use an old version of this module. I'm trying to find a proper solution, rather than just continually hacking it to make it work.

Does anyone know what actually causes this, and know a correct way to fix it using recommended versions of all packages?

Comment: The original bug was resolved in System.Net.Http  version 4.3.1 -see [Inheritance sec rules violated by type: 'System.Net.Http.WebRequestHandler'.](//stackoverflow.com/a/42696376)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution turned out to be much simpler than I expected. I removed the System.Net.Http reference entirely from web.config and now it works correctly.

Answer (score 4):

I saw this error trying to instantiate KeyVaultClient. I was able to fix it by installing nuget package System.Net.Http v4.3.2.

Comment: While this may fix the issue being encountered, it does that through hiding it instead of addressing the cause.

Comment: @TanveerBadar can you explain why

Answer (score 1):

It must be a System.Net.Http version issue. I ran my code in VS 2015, it threw excpetion

    
    
 
Then, I ran my code in VS 2017, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can also verify if you have "Skip applying binding redirects" checked in your options.

Visual studio is updating your web.config file as a result if it is unchecked.