# Unable to integrate OpenXML (documentformat.openxml.*) in C# bot framework, getting the error " Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException "

Tags: c#, .net, botframework, openxml, openxml-sdk

In order to refine a powerpoint(.pptx) file, I have used OpenXML SDK(DocumentFormat.OpenXML) which works fine as a console Application.
However, as the requirement was to implement the same in bot framework, I have added the required nuget package, viz., 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml.*'. The call to a new 
Dialog in the messageController throws an error at this line:

```
await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new Dialogs.RootDialog());
```

Bot works fine in emulator until I add the nuget package 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml.*'. However, it throws the mentioned error. Could not find relevant articles.

complete Method Code:

```
public class MessagesController : ApiController
{

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
    {

        try
        {
            if (activity.GetActivityType() == ActivityTypes.Message)
            {
                await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new Dialogs.RootDialog());
            }
            else
            {
                HandleSystemMessage(activity);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            activity.CreateReply(ex.Message);
        }
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        return response;
    }
```

**Exception:**

> An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = IPostToBot (DelegateActivator), Services = [Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.IPostToBot], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = Shared, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = QueueDrainingDialogTask (ReflectionActivator), Services = [Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.QueueDrainingDialogTask (Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.IPostToBot)], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = Shared, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = IBotToUser (DelegateActivator), Services = [Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.IBotToUser], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = Shared, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = AlwaysSendDirect_BotToUser (ReflectionActivator), Services = [Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.AlwaysSendDirect_BotToUser (Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.IBotToUser), Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.AlwaysSendDirect_BotToUser], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = Shared, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = IConnectorClient (DelegateActivator), Services = [Microsoft.Bot.Connector.IConnectorClient], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = None, Ownership = ExternallyOwned ---> An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = ConnectorClientFactory (DelegateActivator), Services = [Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.IConnectorClientFactory], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = None, Ownership = ExternallyOwned ---> Inheritance security rules violated by type: 'System.Net.Http.WebRequestHandler'. Derived types must either match the security accessibility of the base type or be less accessible. (See inner exception for details.) (See inner exception for details.) (See inner exception for details.) (See inner exception for details.) (See inner exception for details.) (See inner exception for details.)

**Inner Exception:**

> An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = QueueDrainingDialogTask (ReflectionActivator), Services = [Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.QueueDrainingDialogTask (Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.IPostToBot)], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = Shared, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = IBotToUser (DelegateActivator), Services = [Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.IBotToUser], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = Shared, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = AlwaysSendDirect_BotToUser (ReflectionActivator), Services = [Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.AlwaysSendDirect_BotToUser (Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.IBotToUser), Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.AlwaysSendDirect_BotToUser], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = Shared, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = IConnectorClient (DelegateActivator), Services = [Microsoft.Bot.Connector.IConnectorClient], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = None, Ownership = ExternallyOwned ---> An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = ConnectorClientFactory (DelegateActivator), Services = [Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.IConnectorClientFactory], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = None, Ownership = ExternallyOwned ---> Inheritance security rules violated by type: 'System.Net.Http.WebRequestHandler'. Derived types must either match the security accessibility of the base type or be less accessible. (See inner exception for details.) (See inner exception for details.) (See inner exception for details.) (See inner exception for details.) (See inner exception for details.)

**Stack Trace:**

> at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
>      at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.<Execute>b__5_0()
>      at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.GetOrCreateAndShare(Guid id, Func`1 creator)
>      at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute()
>      at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
>      at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
>      at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
>      at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance)
>      at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
>      at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve[TService](IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
>      at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve[TService](IComponentContext context)
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Conversation.d__11.MoveNext() in D:\a\1\s\CSharp\Library\Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Autofac\Dialogs\Conversation.cs:line 0
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Conversation.d__6.MoveNext() in D:\a\1\s\CSharp\Library\Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Autofac\Dialogs\Conversation.cs:line 108
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>      at CredentialsAutomation.MessagesController.d__0.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Tanu\source\repos\CredentialsAutomation\CredentialsAutomation\Controllers\MessagesController.cs:line 27

Comment: _"Bot works fine in emulator until I add the nuget package 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml."_ - So do you get the error after you've added the package even without using it in the bot code?

Comment: Yes, it was only after I added this package that i started getting this error.

Comment: As your inner exception is saying "See inner exception for details" it looks like you might have to walk all the way down the chain of inner exceptions to find the one that's actually going to tell you what the problem is.

Comment: I have checked the inner most exception 
((System.TypeLoadException)ex.InnerException.InnerException.InnerException.InnerException.InnerException.InnerException).Message

" Inheritance security rules violated by type: 'System.Net.Http.WebRequestHandler'. Derived types must either match the security accessibility of the base type or be less accessible. "

Comment: If you remove the OpenXML package, does the problem go away? Or, when you added it, did it update any dependencies? See [here](https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/6) and [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/11100) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42938814/inheritance-security-rules-violated-by-type-system-net-http-webrequesthandler) - this error can occur with specific versions of the web API components.

Comment: The error remains the same even if the package is uninstalled. I could not find any such dependencies for which the reference could be removed.

Comment: I am looking for alternative nuget package to work in bot framework with powerpoint, would it be fine to use Microsoft.Interop...

Comment: Interop would require PowerPoint to be installed, which woudn't be possible on a default deployment to Azure. If you were hosting the bot yourself, though, say on a VM, then it might work. It may depend on what you're actually doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all those who have been working on a similar problem, the solution would be to proceed with following OpenXml nuget packages:

DocumentFormat.OpenXml;

DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation;

DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;